# I withdrew from my graduate program and have a 3.6 graduate gpa. Can I apply to another university?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I withdrew from my graduate studies due to academic bullying from a professor I would continually have throughout the rest of my graduate studies. I was given F's and C's in classes taught by that professor and they were deliberate no matter how precise my answers were. I took it to the Dean but he her friend and I showed him the assignments and tests and he refused to "go on a witch hunt" as he would say. Therefore I decided to leave before my gpa dropped drastically and get kicked out for academic deficiency. There were also blatant attacks and passive agressiveness during the lectures and conversations I had with the professor. I did the right thing it was obvious there was foul play. What I wanted to know is if I have a chance at being accepted by another graduate program? I can get letters from other professors from my department as I always scored A's in every other class not taught by this tyrant professor.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.

Try to distinguish between confiding in a close friend or relative, or a therapist, vs. presenting your situation to a potential teacher, administrator or colleague.  With the former, you can provide details and get moral support.  With the latter, keep it short and simple.